# How to open,edit and save a word file stored in the server using ASP .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, server, ms-word

I have a server where word files are stored, i want by pressing a link the user can open the word file from the server, edit in it then saving it back to the server.
till now i figured out that i cant do so directly, but to save the file locally , edit on it then upload it back again.
so is there is a better way to do so? if not how to wait till the file is saved then automatically be uploaded again .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet is probably to look into some of the controls out there you can buy to do this. Not necessarily cheap but depends on how much you need this functionality:

https://www.syncfusion.com/aspnet-mvc-ui-controls/word-processor

Regarding detecting a file change locally... you can use the FileSystemWatcher to do this on a folder... this isn't something that will work inherently from a website though. YOu would need to implement and distribute a windows service that your users would install and they would need to download the file they were changing into the folder(s) that your FileSystemWatcher was watching...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.8

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer

Hope this helps.